# Is a universe with zero Planck's constant possible? If so, what is the behaviour of light and matter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, universe, physical-constants

A universe in which Planck's constant is zero has no quantum physics i.e, is not governed by quantum physics. If we assume such a universe exist, will radiation especially light still exist? Will matter exist?

Comment: Do you consider Newtonian mechanics plus Maxwell's equations a universe?  What about special relativity?

Comment: I consider each of them describing the universe from their own viewpoint.

Comment: Matter is catastrophically unstable without quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

With the EM field no longer quantized, the UV catastrophe would be real: any temperature would emit infinite energy. (And $\alpha = e^2/\hbar c$ would lead to strong coupling).

Temperature would also fail, as statistical mechanics relies on a "state" having a finite volume in phase-space ( the volume goes as $1/\hbar^3$), so entropy would be infinite at nano-temperature.

Atoms fail, of course. The Rydberg constant:

$$ R_{\infty} = \frac{m_ee^4}{8\epsilon_0^2\hbar^3c}$$

goes south (or north, maybe).

So a proton and electron would just bind with infinite energy....if an electron would even exist, as it is a quantum of the electron field, but without the Q in QFT, it's difficult to say...would electrons just be continuous?

And the proton? We can't solve classical SU(3) field theory, so who knows.

So matter and energy would be problematic.

The Planck length, mass, time, charge, energy all go to zero, while the density diverges. We don't have a quantum theory of gravity...whether that prevents spacetime from existing is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is much too open-ended to be answerable in general, since you've evaded WillO's question trying to get you to pin down what you really mean. However, I would say broadly that such a universe can't be an interesting one unless you make other changes to the laws of physics. It won't have stable matter because a classical system of charged particles doesn't have a stable equilibrium. It also won't be self-consistent, because an electron would have an infinite energy contained in its electric field, and therefore an infinite inertia.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum physics is based on the existence of a non-zero collection of quanta of energy $h\nu$ that we call radiation. If radiation is zero or doesn't exist all the definitions involving QP will change or lose all the sense, respectively.

Comment: You mean to say quantum mechanics exist because radiations exist? What about radiations having only wave nature and not particle nature?

Comment: All kind of radiation explained in the context of QP exhibit wave-particle duality. This duality is one of the pillars of the QP, without it, QP has no sense.